# Bash Script - Expect does not send password that ends with $!. Also need improvement to report connection timed out

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell-scripting, expect

Update: Password issue is fixed and connection timed out message was fixed too.

Adding `\` before `$!` worked. Example: `*password\$!`

```
set passwds { *password\$! @tempP@ss %Test4%}
```

For connection timed out, added the below code after "s password:" line

```
timeout { puts stdout "$server_address : connection timed out"}
```

This script does not report if the connection times out. It just jumps to the next IP. If it reported connection timed out, then i could grep and find all the IP's easily and do something.

I want this part of the code to report if connection failed

```
ssh -t root@$server_address "$*"
```

Also this script fails to send passwords that ends with $!. 
The password is *password$! but it sends it as *password

Expect debug with `exp_internal 1`:

```
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\r\nroot@10.10.10.10's password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\r\nroot@10.10.10.10's password: "
send: sending "*password\r" to { exp4 }
expect: continuing expect
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
(( $# != 1 )) && { echo >&2 "Usage: $0 \"[COMMAND]\""; exit 1; }
servers_addresses=(10.10.10.10)
for server_address in ${servers_addresses[@]}; do
        expect <<EOF
set passwds { *password$! @tempP@ss %Test4%}
set i 0
spawn ssh -t root@$server_address "$*"
expect {
    "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
    "s password:" { send "[lindex \$passwords_ssh \$x]\r"; incr x; exp_continue }
    eof
}
EOF
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables get expanded if used in double `""` quotes, and Bash treats everything starting with `$` as a variable.

Use single quotes `''` instead.

`ssh` will end with an exit code <> 0 if an error occurred. This is stored in `$?`

Comment: where exactly am i supposed to that? can you modify that line and paste it here? just that line?

Comment: Try `set passwds { '*password$!' '@tempP@ss' '%Test4%'}`

Comment: Well that did not work. It is now sending password as "'password'\r"
Debug info: send: sending "'password'\r" to { exp4 }